# How to prevent my app from opening within another app?

Tags: android, phonegap

I have an app called 'MyApp' which I can launch from the Android phone by clicking on the icon and it creates its own instance.

Now, I am linking to this app from with the LINE messenger application with `myapp://`. It opens the app fine and it works, but the problem is, I noticed that now my app runs within the LINE messenger app. So I have my app open twice, once as its own instance and once right within the LINE application. If I check all open apps, I see it open twice.

It's hard to explain but you probably know what I mean. My app is running but with the icon of the LINE application. I can exit it and it takes me back to that app.

How can I "break out" of this application and ensure it runs in its own instance? Or if its own instance isn't running yet, create it?

I am using PhoneGap build and included this in config.xml which I hoped would do the trick but apparently doesn't:

```
<widget>

  <platform name="android">

    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" 
                 target="/manifest/application" 
                 mode="merge">

       <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" />
       <activity android:configChanges="orientation" />

    </edit-config>

  </platform>

</widget>
```

Any ideas what else I need to do?

Comment: "So I have my app open twice, once as its own instance and once right within the LINE application" -- no, your app is open once. Your activities appear in two tasks. To draw an analogy, when a user opens two tabs on your Web site, they are not starting two copies of your Web server. I don't know enough of PhoneGap to steer you specifically; in native Android development, `android:taskAffinity` or `android:launchMode` attributes on the `<activity>` element controls this somewhat.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to the comment above.

In PhoneGap, all you need to do is add this to config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

Or you can include this:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: Mind that singleTask is vulnerable to task hijacking (https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity15/sec15-paper-ren-chuangang.pdf). Using singleInstance and setting taskAffinity to an empty string may be a better option.